# How to convert lidar .bag data to point cloud

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I want to create the point cloud from the lidar data.
I have bag file of velodyne lidar data with that i want to create  point cloud.
using rviz i can view the data properly but can not generate the point cloud.
I go through tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler/Tutorials/HowToAssembleLaserScans but not able to understand how to use **Point Cloud Assembler** . Please can anyone help me with this and simplify it for me...
thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249278/how-to-convert-lidar-.bag-data-to-point-cloud/) by [Nikka](https://answers.ros.org/users/28163/nikka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS Velodyne driver is different from other LIDARs in that it does not publish standard [LaserScan](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) messages, but [VelodyneScan](http://docs.ros.org/api/velodyne_msgs/html/msg/VelodyneScan.html) ones. These have to be converted to the standard [PointCloud2](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html) message format using an additional step. How this works is described on the [velodyne_pointcloud](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_pointcloud) wiki page.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nikka](https://answers.ros.org/users/28163/nikka/) on 2016-12-05**:
thank you stefan.
After it converted in standard PointCloude2 massage format, still its not creating the point cloud. In rviz its giving me moving data Its not creating solid point cloud.
can you please help me with this is there anything else that i can try?